# Homtopy and "breaking" loops

Tags: algebraic-topology

I see that the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ can detect holes in some cases. For example, when picturing $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S^1$ and imagining a loop that goes around the hole, one cant deform it into a path that starts at the same point $x_0$ but does not go around the hole. As far as I understand, this is because one would have to break the loop, or when imagining it as a string, cut the string, deform it and then glue it back together. One could also picture this as determining some point $x_1$ and then slowly moving the points that are left and right of $x_1$ further away. However, in Hatchers book on algebraic topology, there is one example in the section preceding the introduction to the fundamental group, which gives the following picture (note that this is an example in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^1$, or rather an embedded circle). [image]

When thinking of this process from left to right, wouldnt this also be a kind of breaking of the loop? Why is this allowed / doesn't harm continuity but the example I gave does? What is the key difference here? Maybe I am overseeing something obvious, but I guess my intuition just isn't sharp enough.

Comment: Also, It's worth pointing out that there is a difference in the picture between the circle $A$ and the loop $B$. Since you're in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^1$, the loop cannot cross through the circle because the circle has been removed from the space. However, the loop $B$ can cross itself because it does not need to be injective to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t,x)$ be the homotopy where $t$ is time and $x \in [0, 1]$ is a point in the domain of the curve.

So you have here a picture where

- $f(t_1,0) = x_0$: the start of the curve at time $t_1$ is $x_0$
- $f(t_1,\frac12) = x_0$: halfway through the curve at time $t_1$ you are also back at $x_0$
- $f(t_1,1) = x_0$

Now let's check the definition of a homotopy of closed paths:

- $f(t, 0) = f(t,1)$ is constant for all times $t$ (meaning the start and end is always $x_0$
- $f$ is continuous, meaning a small change in time or a small change in $x$ yields a small change in $f$

Except for the endpoints, nowhere does it say that if $f(t,x) = f(t,y)$ (the loop intersects itself) then that equation must be true for all $t$.

Here is a one dimensional picture that might be helpful to you:

[image: homotopy in 1 dimension]

The change is continuous, a small change in $t$ or $x$ yields a small change in $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, why isn't this also the case for my loop around a circle example? The time $t$ would control the distance of the breaking. Meaning at $t=0$ I have the entire loop, then I break the loop somewhere and move those segments steadily and slowly with $t$, until I reacht $t=1$ where they are connected again.

Comment: @user324789 Do you have $f(t,0) = x_0$ and $f(t,1) = x_0$ for all $t$ in your example?

Comment: Yes I do, picture $S^1$ with $x_0=(0,1)$ and $x_1=(0,-1)$ and then breaking it in $x_1$. The problem is then, that it is not continuous in the 2nd variable I suppose, since for $t=1/2$ I would have a fixed distance for some points, when plugging in values. For continuity, does it suffice to check if it is continuous when fixing either the 1st or 2nd variable? I am unsure right now..

Comment: @user324789 I don't think so but it is certainly true that if $f(x,y)$ is continuous then so are $f(x_0,y)$ and $f(x,y_0)$ for any constants $x_0, y_0$. Since we don't actually have an explicit function we cannot actually "check that it is continuous."

See the difference here is $f(t,0.5)$ is not close to $f(t,0.5 + \varepsilon)$ whereas in the picture you have in your question the points that are moving away from each other are $f(t,0)$ and $f(t,0.5)$ which is allowed.